# Format in TSQL of simple 'Merge into' query using 'Case'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-update, case

I have a TSQL UPDATE query as follows:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Value = CASE
    WHEN (Condition1 = 'A') AND (Condition2 = '1') THEN 'BLAH-1'
    WHEN (Condition1 = 'B') AND (Condition2 = '1') THEN 'BLAH-2'
END
WHERE (Condition1 IN ('A','B')) AND (Condition2 IN ('1'))
```

Can someone show me the format for the above as a 'MERGE INTO' query, if it is possible?

```
MERGE INTO Table
USING ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ... VALUES ...
```

In other words, if (Condition1) AND (Condition2) don't exist, then add the records to the table.

If it helps, the various 'cases' will either all need to be UPDATED or all INSERTED.

I am using SQL server 2012.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have developed the code a bit as follows, it's still a work in progress. Luckily I only have to check one combination of Condition1 and Condition2 to see whether ALL the records need to be updated or inserted:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Condition1 = 'A') AND (Condition2 = '1')) 
UPDATE Table 
SET Value = CASE
WHEN (Condition1 = 'A') AND (Condition2 = '1') THEN 'BLAH-1'
WHEN (Condition1 = 'B') AND (Condition2 = '1') THEN 'BLAH-2'
END
WHERE (Condition1 IN ('A','B')) AND (Condition2 IN ('1'))
ELSE
INSERT INTO Table (Condition1, Condition2)
VALUES ('A','1'),('B','1')
```

Comment: As far as I know in Merge one is suppose to match the column values to decide whether to update or insert, but not conditional statements.

Comment: What is preventing you from constructing the MERGE yourself? You appear to have found the syntax already. Any **specific** question?

Comment: Thanks. usr - I wasn't sure where exactly to fit the CASE bit into the syntax; I'm new to SQL server and not that confident with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think merge is necessarily meant to be used in the way you are describing, and if you got it to work it would be somewhat inscrutable code. Merge is meant to compare defined column relations between tables and either update or insert into the tables depending on those relations. I think you are better off just using a couple IF...INSERT ... ELSE ... UPDATE... statements. It would be just as fast and easier to read for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code a bit (see Update above). Any input is much appreciated.